# Bad performance when use RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I'm developing a search contact feature, in that screen, there is a **RecyclerView** inside **NestedScrolView** (*fillViewport = true*).
Screen design: *(**This design is accepted by customer, I can't change it**)*
 
[image]

 After loading all contacts of current device into an ArrayList, the search results are filtered from this array.
There is several cases that make the app very **laggy**:
 1. When user type an input that have *no result*, then user *clear search*, I have to show *all results* again. *The **NestedScrollView** has to render UI for all items of **RecyclerView** (for example: 300 items).*
 2. When the quantity of results has many changes (for example, from 1 to 300 items). *The **NestedScrollView** has to render UI for a lot of items of **RecyclerView***

I know this design breaks recycling technique of RecyclerView, but I can't change it. 
What I tried:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

In AndroidManifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

The adapter:

```
public class RecyclerContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerContactAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<MobileContact> contacts;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerContactAdapter() {
        contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        this.context = parent.getContext();
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_contact, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //set data for view
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contacts.size();
    }

    protected class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvAlphabetHeader;
        private CircleImageView civAvatar;
        private TextView tvContactName;
        private TextView tvStatus;
        private CheckBox cbInvited;
        private RelativeLayout rlAlphabetHeader;
        private RelativeLayout rlContainer;

        protected ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvAlphabetHeader = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_recycler_contact_tv_alphabet_header);
            civAvatar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_recycler_contact_civ_avatar);
            tvContactName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_recycler_contact_tv_name);
            tvStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_recycler_contact_tv_status);
            cbInvited = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_recycler_contact_cb_contact);
            rlAlphabetHeader =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_recycler_contact_rl_alphabet);
            rlContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_recycler_contact_rl_contact);
        }
    }

    public void addAll(List<MobileContact> mobileContacts) {
        this.contacts.clear();
        this.contacts.addAll(mobileContacts);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void add(MobileContact mobileContact) {
        this.contacts.add(mobileContact);
    }

    public List<MobileContact> getContacts() {
        return this.contacts;
    }

}
```

Comment: post your recyler adapter

Comment: Could you explain your ui design a bit more? What part of this is scrollable? Ie you can scroll nestedscrollview and also recyclerview inside nestedscrollview or what?

Comment: @Okas except toolbar, user can scroll the whole screen

Comment: @ErginErsoy okay, I'm gonna post it, if I don't use NestedScrollView, this feature works smoothly cause the recycling technique.

Comment: **Why is a ScrollView needed** at all, when the RecyclerView is already scrollable by itself?!

Comment: use scroll for main layout and use `app:fastScrollEnabled="true"`

Comment: @NoiseGenerator because user can scroll header and search box also, the idea of Okas is maybe right (event it's pretty complicated), use different item type for RecyclerView.

Comment: I would'n scroll the header and the searchbox. Makes more sense, to me.

Comment: yep, I know it's not the best practice for UI, but the designer team made it and I can't change. When keyboard is showed, it needs more space to show the results, then it should be scrolled up

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are using RecyclerView incorrectly. Instead of putting your RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView put your "Header" and "Search  box" inside RecyclerView as different view types.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245463/3964585) is a good example.

Comment: this method sounds appropriate, but there will be 4 different view types: header (TextView), a button,  a search box, normal item, it's complicated when handle all events for each.

Comment: It only seems complicated at first. Actually this is standard practice. Also looking at your ui it seems you can put your header, button and search box together in one layout, so it will be only two view types.

Comment: oh I see, I wish I could show you the exact screen design. I will try your solution

Comment: What if I have a fragment over the List, I cannot move all the logic from the fragment to the header in the adapter? And fragments cannot be used inside adapters.

Comment: @David, you probably have to redesign.

Comment: What if the recyclerview has GridLayoutManager?!! How to make header for example be horizontal?

Comment: @hiddeneyes02 for GridLayoutManager you can configer span amount depending of view type

Comment: ConcatAdapter would fit perfectly for this situation since you will have two adapters and you will not bother yourself with view type at all; because adding both in one adapter will need a lot of handling if your data changes frequently specially if you are using ListAdapter since you will need to add your header always at the beginning of the data. on the other side using ConcatAdapter will give you two separate adapters and you can update them separately here is good article on how to make it. https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/get-ahead-using-headers-in-recyclerview-2909a69b19